# html and css ....background doesnt work

Tags: html, css, background-image

**css**

```
#part1 {
  background: url("img/00.jpg") repeat 0 0;
}

#part1 {
  background: url("../img/00.jpg") repeat 0 0;
}

#part1 {
  background-image: url("../img/00.jpg") repeat 0 0;
}
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>hello there</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <div id="part1">hello there</div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

but still the background image doesnt display ...except a white background.Can anyone help....I stored the image in a folder named img

Answer (score 1):

In your code example you are targetting the same element with 3 different CSS rules. Because of this, only the last rule will be applied, as it will override the other 2.

Make sure that you are defining the correct path to the image based on your file structure.

```css
#part1 { 
  background: url("http://patcreator.appspot.com/imgs/textures/light/light-texture-01.jpg") repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="part1">hello there</div>
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the path to the img is case sensitive.

Answer (score -2):

To see the background your  should have at least  width:100px; and height:100px; try this

`#part1{
        background: url("img/00.jpg") repeat 0 0;
        min-height:100px;
    }`

Also check browser console if image not found !